# Headless Computer Running Ubuntu on Ethernet Connection Dropping after Power Outage

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I run a headless computer using Ubuntu on my LAN and when necessary, access it using NoMachine and SSH. The computer is connected via Ethernet. Last night, I had a brief power outage that lasted for 30 seconds. Needless to say, the computer crashed since it is not on a UPS. After power was restored, I turned on the computer and went back to what I was working on over my SSH connection when the computer suddenly disconnected. I couldn't make any inbound connections to the machine, and the outbound connections that were established on the machine had dropped as well. I thought perhaps this might be a one-off thing, but it wasn't. The issue has been arbitrarily popping up all day today and I can't figure out how to fix it.

What makes debugging this particularly difficult is that since I rely on connecting to the computer over the network, I can't access logs or anything after the computer's connection drops, and I have crash the computer and restart it.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be wrong or can offer suggestions about where to look for solving this problem? If it matters, the specific version of Ubuntu that I am using is Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster).

Comment: are your logs cleared on boot or in RAM only?

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately I don't know the answer to this since I'm not sure what logs I should be looking at.

Comment: `/var/logs` would be a start - look for log entries around the time(s) you lose connection

Comment: Start with the last entries of the "previous boot" logs. As you have systemd, `journalctl -b -1 -n 200` would be a good start – though if the system crashes, the most interesting messages likely will not get stored at all; you'll probably need to set up Netconsole (or drag a spare monitor to the system).

Comment: After some toying around, I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and it happened again. I tried Windows and it also happened with it too, so I think it's safe to say that it's a hardware issue.